# A potential error trying to establish ssh with ec2 aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, terminal

So, I have an ubuntu ec2 instance running, and wanted to establish an ssh(I am an Ubuntu 16.04 user). However, I do not think that I get the right response when I try to:

```
huzeyfekiran@huzeyfekiran-ThinkPad-L450:~/Downloads$ chmod 400 mykeypair.pem
huzeyfekiran@huzeyfekiran-ThinkPad-L450:~/Downloads$ ssh -i mykeypair.pem ubuntu@ec2-18-219-42-124.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-18-219-42-124.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (18.219.42.124)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:T9J5/BH9RmALnv/6n4rUu0tw8nIFHn8zYvM9BwwP3fA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-18-219-42-124.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com,18.219.42.124' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1047-aws x86_64)
 * Documentation:  
 * Management:     
 * Support:        
  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

I think that I do not get the right respond because when I try to connect to ec2 instance via jupyter notebook, the browser cant establish a connection and I am sure that I have firewall turned off. So, is there a problem with the SSH?

Comment: The output you've shown suggests that you *are* connected to the EC2 instance via ssh. If you're running a remote Jupyter notebook on the EC2 instance in no-browser mode and you want to connect to it from a browser on your computer then you need to tunnel over SSH (see https://coderwall.com/p/y1rwfw/jupyter-notebook-on-remote-server).

Comment: I think I am a bit confused here. So, to run jupyter notebook on EC2 instance, I used to copy the DNS link and just add :8888 part to the end of it. Isnt that considered tunneling over SSH?

Comment: Have you followed the AWS documention on how to run Jupyter Notebook on EC2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mxnet/latest/dg/setup-jupyter.html)?